# How set time in php to get data using date

Tags: php, mysql, database, timestamp

here is the script code of my page. 
i select any date and i get the data by selecting date from the database.
i want to initially set the date to today when i open my page.
then i get the data of today and of current time. 
but how ???
i give you an example: [this is example link.](http://joomusic.info/joosilver.php) 
here you can see timestamp box to show results of current date and time 
i want to do it exactly like this. 
but how?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tcal.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="tcal.js"></script>
<form action="index.php" method="get">
From : <input type="text" name="d1" class="tcal" value="" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<table id="resultTable" data-responsive="table" style="text-align: left; width: 400px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> Birtday </th>
<th> Name </th>
<th> Gender </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
include('connect.php');
if (isset($_GET["d1"])) { $d1  = $_GET["d1"]; } else { $d1="0000-00-00"; }; 
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM birthday WHERE date = :a");
$result->bindParam(':a', $d1);
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>
<tr class="record">
<td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
if (isset($_GET["d1"])) { $d1  = $_GET["d1"]; } else { $d1="0000-00-00"; };
```

with

```
if (isset($_GET["d1"])) { $d1  = $_GET["d1"]; } else { $d1=date('"Y-m-d"); };
```

or even shorter

```
$d1 = isset($_GET["d1"]) ? $_GET["d1"] : date('"Y-m-d");
```

to set the current date as the initial date.

Your other question is "How do i get a calendar to select a date" right? If so, just google ["How do i get a calendar to select a date with php"](https://www.google.com/search?q=How%20do%20i%20get%20a%20calendar%20to%20select%20a%20date%20with%20php). Or search for [PHP Calendar select](https://www.google.de/search?q=php%20date%20select&oq=php%20date%20select).

This is not a free "write my code for me" website by the way. Sorry.

Comment: @addresch-serj i add this $d1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); in mysql database i have set date colum on timestamp but i can't get data by selecting date

Comment: if (isset($_GET["d1"])) { $d1  = $_GET["d1"]; } else { $d1=date('"Y-m-d"'); };

Missing bracket in code. please correct with above line

Answer (score 0):

To get current time and date, you can use the `date` function. For example:

```
  $d1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

It will give you something like:

```
  "2014-03-14 08:52:30"
```

Comment: hey i add this $d1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); in mysql database i have set date colum on timestamp but i can't get data by selecting date

Comment: i give you already one example link http://joomusic.info/joosilver.php this is connect with timestamp i want to connect my script with timestamp to get data from current date and time

Comment: Excuseme, what do you mean with: "i can't get data by selecting date" ?

Comment: visit here for for understand http://joomusic.info/joosilver.php if i select the any date then i get data from database but i want to set this automatic if i visit on my page then i want to get data of today date .. like timestamp ...